# Thorax 2.0.1 is throwing `Cannot read property '_thoraxBind' of undefined` when constructing my View

Tags: javascript, undefined

With the following [Thorax 2.0.1](http://thoraxjs.org/) code:

```js
MyView = Thorax.View.extend({
    events: {
        'foo': 'bar'
    },
    template: 'Hello world'
});

foo = new MyView();

foo.bar = function() {}
```

I am getting the following error when I attempt to create the view:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_thoraxBind' of undefined   [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  _.extend._addEvent                                                  [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  (anonymous function)                                                [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  j.each.j.forEach                                                          underscore.js:79
  _.extend.on                                                         [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  (anonymous function)                                                [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  j.each.j.forEach                                                          underscore.js:87
  h                                                                   [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  at.event.configure                                                  [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  (anonymous function)                                                [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  j.each.j.forEach                                                          underscore.js:87
  ot.View.Backbone.View.extend._configure                             [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  a.View                                                        [VM] backbone-min.js (848):1
  ot.View.Backbone.View.extend.constructor                            [VM] thorax.js (849):1
  r                                                             [VM] backbone-min.js (848):1
  (anonymous function)                                                             main.js:8
```

Here is a [minimal reproduction](https://gist.github.com/jesstelford/6687044).

Why is this error occurring?

***PS**: Can someone with higher rep add the `thorax` tag? Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Thorax requires all events specified in the `events` hash to exist on the object at time of instantiation. There are two possible solutions:

## Add function before object instantiation

```js
// Add 'bar' function to object before instantiation
MyView = Thorax.View.extend({
    events: {
        'foo': 'bar'
    },
    template: 'Hello world'
});

MyView.prototype.bar = function() {}

foo = new MyView();
```

## Use Anonymous function to wrap call

If you are dynamically adding the function at a later time, you can also do the following:

```js
// Wrap call to this.bar in anonymous function to satisfy Thorax
MyView = Thorax.View.extend({
    events: {
        'foo': function(e) { this.bar(e); }
    },
    template: 'Hello world'
});

foo = new MyView();

foo.bar = function() {}
```